# Implicit chain constructor in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, language-design, roslyn

Why is there no implicit chain constructor to the base class?

What I mean? Let's look at the following classes:

```
class Person
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

class EnhancedPerson : Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

If you try and compile this code it won't compile. As you can see `Person` depends on a name and makes it clear, you won't construct a `Person` without a `Name`.

Why is there no implicit `EnhancedPerson` constructor, who chains to the base constructor for each `Person` constructor?

Just to contestualize: I started asking myself this question creating controllers with injectable dependencies since some of those dependencies were present in all of my controllers (and I wanted to make it clear that they were needed), I created a base class and I found out that it is very annoying to re-create all the constructors...

P.s. I do know that there are also some others programming patters like having a public no-arguments constructor and public properties for dependencies, but ... that's another story.

I'm not looking for a way to reimplement this, I'm just trying to understand why it's not possible or why it was not done.

Comment: It most is likely inherited from C++ as in C++ constructors aren't inherited implicitly.

Comment: So the main reason in your opinion is because c# is a language who inheritted some basic rules from c++ it was just made that way ?

Comment: I think it's a matter of explicitness. I would want to know any dependency my class has, no matter how deep in the chain they are.

Comment: @L.Trabacchin Yes i think so, but lets see what Jon Skeet will tell you when he comes around.

Comment: I can see that an implied constructor might be a convenience, but there may be cases where it is not desired, so there would need to be some way to disable it. And while this may have been influenced by C++, I note that neither VB nor C# have "implied constructors".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "real" reason can only be answered by the people who defined the language, but I can speculate...

There are various compile time errors that can be resolved automatically, for example:

```
int mul(int c, int n) {
  int total = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    total += c;
  return total
}
```

Code above has 3 errors, with 3 obvious solutions:

1. `i` is undefined
   A compiler could easily deduce `i` to be an `int` type and be local to the `for` statement.
2. The `for` block is missing the closing curly bracket
   A compiler could "be smart about it" and know that the missing bracket is before the `return ...` statement merely because having a `return` as part of the `for` block without any branching makes no sense.
3. `return total` is missing a semicolon
   Obviously simple to "auto-correct" at compile time.

So why doesn't the compiler do that? why doesn't this happen in any language really?
Well, the simple reason is that it's just dangerous without justification. Yes, these all seem like logical solutions to small mistakes or details overlooked, but in reality letting the compiler iron-out these types of problems can cause a lot of unexplained behavior (what if the developer really did want to return after the first iteration?). On the other hand, the cost of *not* solving these issues and alerting them instead is quite cheap. It lets the developer know exactly what's wrong and if the solution really is that simple it should take no more then a few moments to correct manually.

The trade-off here is quite easy to choose, provide the developer with enough information so that the issues can be solved quickly and leave nothing to chance!

The same holds true to the "implicit inherited constructor" suggested in the question... Yes, the compiler could do that, easily... but what if the developer really meant to do some real work in the constructor, but forgot? shouldn't the compiler assist by erroring out of the compilation?

Comment: `but what if the developer really meant to do some real work in the constructor?` - then you override the constructor as in any other language.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy - But a theoretical compiler that implicitly creates a constructor for you won't inform the developer of the missing constructor, so it's easy to miss. That's the point of my answer.

Comment: @Amit Ok so your point is military grade reliability, what isn't there can't broke... makes sense to me.

But i would add one more point: implicit constructor are already there, they just go away as soon as you write one, why not wiring them ?

Comment: @L.Trabacchin Implicit constructors are empty constructors that do nothing (well, they initialize members to default values...). Having a parametric constructor is different. Again, yes, a decision could be made that inherited classes implicitly create pass-through constructors but that hides potential mistakes where "real work" is being done, contrary to implicit empty constructors that "do nothing".

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy Sorry i misunderstood what you wrote

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy I thinked about the _then you override the constructor as in any other language_ and i'm not really sure of what happens in other languages, BUT, actually there is one reason why constructors behave differently from normal functions in .net even if they just actually are. They can't be overridden because they are needed at every level of the inheritance... **I think** this is because if B inherit A, then A gets constructed before B.

Comment: @L.Trabacchin With `override` I was referring to implicitly inherited constructors or so called [default constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645608(v=vs.71).aspx). So if a constructor is inherited implicitly you can override it to add your own code.

Comment: The three examples you gave can each be fixed with a constant amount of additional code. The duplication of the constructor redirect into the descendant types can introduce more redundant code since there can be multiple parameters in a constructor.

Comment: After a few days of thinking the reason i liked more is the **"What isn't there can't break"** this is a good enough answer to me

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am being naive here, but this is my understanding

**Sample 1**

```
class Person
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

**Sample 1** expresses that the only valid way (according to the author of `Person` class) to create a `Person` object is by providing a `Name`

**Sample 2**

```
class EnhancedPerson : Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

**Sample 2** express that `EnhancedPerson` inherits all data from  `Person`.

This is how I would visualize the compiler trying to build that code when it encounters first usage

> Let's create an EnhancedPerson object. Well, I need to create a Person
>   object for that due to inheritance. OK, so let's create a Person
>   object then. Well, the only valid way to create a Person is by
>   providing the name. So, let's check if EnhancedPerson tells me what
>   should I feed the constructor for Person. Shoot, it doesn't. Stop with
>   an error

**To summarize: To construct `EnhancedPerson` you need to construct `Person` which can be only constructed if you provide a `Name`**

There are 2 usual fixes:

1. Add a default constructor to `Person`, so the compiler can create an "default initialized" object. **Remember that the compiler only provides a default constructor, if the class does not contain any other constructors.**

**Sample 3**

```
    public Person() {
    }
```

2. Add a constructor to `EnhancedPerson` which can provide the `Name` for `Person` sub-object. Below are couple of ways to do it.

**Sample 4**

```
    class EnhancedPerson : Person {
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public EnhancedPerson(string name) : base(name) { }
    }

    class EnhancedPerson : Person {
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public EnhancedPerson() : base(null) { }
    }
```

**NOTE:** Compiler cannot automatically infer the value of `Name` to be null (since the `Person` constructor explicitly requests against it.

**Sample demonstrating the problem with compiler guessing**

In the below example, let's say `txt` contains the age value as a string. You can see what disaster we might have if the compiler passes that automatically to `Person`, since base class has only one constructor which takes a string and `EnhancedPerson` does not have any string properties. Even if a human with all his intelligence has to `hand compile` it (other than the author of `EnhancedPerson`) they cannot tell if `txt` has to be passed to `Person` constructor or not

**Sample 5**

```
class EnhancedPerson : Person {
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public EnhancedPerson(string txt) {
    }
}
```

I hope it is obvious now why a compiler cannot automatically infer how to chain the constructors when the base class constructor **needs** arguments. Different languages provide different mechanisms for specifying which parameter needs to be passed to the base constructor.

Comment: If I understood your theory is that the only way to keep it clear how the derived classes behaves is to explicitly declare it, the compiler can't guess if I want to provide a default name or ask the next developer to provide it...

Comment: Correct. The compiler can't guess, but the author of `Person` or `EnhancedPerson` or both can specify what is this default value for `Name`.

Comment: How does that address the question? The rules & "limitations" are well known and described in the question itself. The question is "**why** doesn't the compiler/language infer a pass through constructor of the same signature(s) as the base constructor(s) when no explicit constrictor is provided?"

Comment: @amit That is what I have explained in so many words. It is not feasible, since compiler might generate inaccurate code. Not even humans can generate the correct code unless they already know the complete context. I will post another sample later to make that clearer

Comment: You're missing the point. It could be made such that if **no constructor** is explicitly defined for `EnhancedPerson`, the statement `new EnhancedPerson("my name")` would implicitly act as a pass through constructor and there are no disambiguations about what should happen. Your answer doesn't address this at any point.

Comment: The question is: Why is there no implicit chain constructor to the base class in c# like languages? I explained that above. If the question was, is it possible to have constructor chaining where specific child class constructor parameters are passed to base class constructor implicitly. Yes, you can write a language with any syntax and rules you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a base class with two (parameterized) constructors. Your inheriting class doesn't want one of those constructors to be used.

You now need to invent *new* syntax just to be able to say "don't let them use this constructor". Whereas the "let me define a constructor, and as part of that, choose which base class constructor to call" is a generally useful construct that you want in the language anyway.

Comment: well i was thinking about the same technology of default constructor, where no constructors means chain constructor, writing one mean i have something to say, use this, it's imperaive